# Constructing an object and calling a method without assignment in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I'm not entirely sure what to call what C# does, so I haven't had any luck searching for the VB.Net equivalent syntax (if it exists, which I suspect it probably doesn't).

In c#, you can do this:

```
public void DoSomething() {
    new MyHelper().DoIt(); // works just fine
}
```

But as far as I can tell, in VB.Net, you must assign the helper object to a local variable or you just get a syntax error:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    New MyHelper().DoIt() ' won't compile
End Sub
```

Just one of those curiosity things I run into from day to day working on mixed language projects - often there is a VB.Net equivalent which uses less than obvious syntax.  Anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The magic word here is Call.

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Call (New MyHelper()).DoIt()
    Call New MyHelper().DoIt()
End Sub
```

Comment: It is magical! Nice for showing both options (with and without parentheses). +1

Answer (score 2):

Gideon Engelberth is right about using Call. It is the best option.

Another option is to use a With statement:

```
With New MyHelper()
    .DoIt()
End With
```

Comment: This is actually the option you should go for it you are calling several methods on your object, for example if you use a `SaveFileDialog` which you are only interested in showing and collection values from, but don't need long term.