# VB.Net calling New without assigning value

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, constructor

In `C#` I can do this:

```
new SomeObjectType("abc", 10);
```

In other words, I can call new without assigning the created instance to any variable. However, in `VB.Net` it seems I cannot do the same thing.

```
New SomeObjectType("abc", 10) ' syntax error
```

Is there a way to do this in `VB.Net`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructing an object and calling a method without assignment in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648700/constructing-an-object-and-calling-a-method-without-assignment-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answers to this other [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648700/2649893#2649893)

So this should work:

```
With New SomeObjectType("abc", 10)
End With
```

Comment: I don't think call won't work since I'm not calling any method, only the constructor. With doesn't really save me much, I may as well just assign it to a variable. Anyway, I guess it's not possible with VB.Net, thanks for the link though.

Comment: Sorry it was one of the other answers I was looking at particularly, I'll update my link, the answer has already been updated to reflect the use of With .. End With

Answer (score 3):

The following works on the Mono VB compiler (`vbnc`, version 0.0.0.5914, Mono 2.4.2 - r):

```
Call New SomeObjectType("abc", 10)
```

Notice the required `Call`.

Comment: @dcp: I compiled it before posting. (Though to be honest I’m on OS X here so I used the Mono compiler.)

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Can you try to compile this (outer quotes added for clarity): "Call New Exception("abc")"  I'm on XP with VS 2008, and that won't compile. Maybe it's a "feature" of Mono :).

Comment: @dcp: That works, too. Weird. Maybe you should report a bug/feature request on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: @dcp  `Call New Exception("abc")` doesn't compile for me either. The editor autocompletes to `Call New Exception("abc")()` and then the compiler says `Error 1 '{' expected.` I also have VS2008 on XP

Comment: Hmm, works fine for me, VS 2013, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648700/constructing-an-object-and-calling-a-method-without-assignment-in-vb-net) it is an accepted answer

Comment: @PavelK: That other question is about **calling a method** on the newly constructed object. `Call (New SomeObjectType("abc", 10)).ToString()` compiles for me, just `Call New SomeObjectType("abc", 10)` doesn't (VS 2019).

Answer (score 1):

One can define a Sub to discard the constructed object:

```
Sub gobble(dummy As Object)
End Sub
```

Then call the constructor as follows:

```
gobble(New SomeClass())
```

I'm using this approach in tests when I test exceptions in constructors. I construct the object in a lambda and pass that lambda to a function that checks for the Exception. Fits nicely on a line.

```
assertThrows(Of ArgumentOutOfRangeException)(Sub() gobble(New ClassUnderTest("stuff")))
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be the correct syntax, e.g.

```
Dim name As New String
Dim url As New Uri("http://www.somedomain.com")
```

Have you got some more code where this is happening?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want to be able to call New without assigning its value to a variable (e.g. in your code above, I want to be able to just do New Uri("http://www.somedomain.com") without the "Dim url As" part preceeding it.

Comment: Yeah, but to do what with it? Doing New Uri("http://www.somedomain.com") without assignment or member access is pretty useless...

Comment: I disagree. It's useful when we need to do failure testing for a constructor. For example, if the constructor cannot take a null argument for its first argument, then we can write a failure test by doing "new SomeObject(null)". There's no need to create a variable here because we are just testing that the expected exception is thrown. Have you never used NUnit or other testing frameworks before?

Comment: I see now, I've never done failure tests like that, always through assignment.

And yes, I use NUnit for all my project work.

Comment: Abbot - It's not a big deal, it's certainly not going to kill me to declare the variable, it's just convenience thing :). And besides, I try to learn something new every day ;).