# syntax error in New Form() With {} vb.net

Tags: vb.net, syntax-error

```
Dim name As String = "hello"
If CType(My.Application.OpenForms(name), Faker) Is Nothing Then
    New Faker() With {.Name = name, .Title = String.Format("{0} - ID:{1}", "hello", Me.ClassClient.ClientAddressID)}.Show()
End If
```

Syntax error in New , if i remove all code and write Dim F As New Faker() With {} and F.show() no error but not work and give me error while running the program object reference not set to an instance of an object

can any one here help me pls

Comment: This is a Windows Forms app targeting .NET Framework?

Comment: @DavidOsborne yea .Net Framework 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answers here [Constructing an object and calling a method without assignment in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648700/constructing-an-object-and-calling-a-method-without-assignment-in-vb-net) that should help.

1. Use `With ... End With`
2. Use `Call`

I think you're having an issue because you're trying to use the C# style of creating an instance of an object without assigning it before chaining a method call.

Your code becomes:

```
Dim name As String = "hello"

If CType(My.Application.OpenForms(name), Faker) Is Nothing Then
    With New Faker() With {.Name = name, .Title = String.Format("{0} - ID:{1}", "hello", Me.ClassClient.ClientAddressID)}

    .Show()
End If
```

Or

```
Dim name As String = "hello"

If CType(My.Application.OpenForms(name), Faker) Is Nothing Then
    Call New Faker() With {.Name = name, .Title = String.Format("{0} - ID:{1}", "hello", Me.ClassClient.ClientAddressID)}.Show()

End If
```